# Is it correct and natural to say "activate a cell phone plan" meaning to get the minutes and internet that come with it?

Tags: word-usage

Could you tell me if it іs it correct and natural to say *activate a cell phone plan* meaning to get the minutes and internet that come with it? For example:

> Sir, if you wish to **activate your cell phone plan**, what you need to do is just top up with 50 dollars.

If it doesn't sound natural, what would you say?

Comment: **Activate** would only be used for a brand-new plan.  If the plan is frozen and needs the money get started again, then you would say **reactivate**.

Comment: "top up with 50 dollars" sounds strange in American English.  *top up* normally takes an object, like *top up the gas tank*, or *top up your account*.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Would you tell me what you would use instead of "top up" in American English?

Comment: We would probably just say **add** fifty dollars.  There's a discussion of the phrasing here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47302/to-top-up-a-mobile-phone

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. Would you please also tell me if you'd say "top off your account with 50 dollars..." in American English?

Comment: You could say "top off your account with 50 dollars", but really, I would not use "top off" at all.  We just do not use that phrase in reference to mobile phones in the US.

Comment: "*What you need to do is just ...*" is unnecessarily wordy. Following the other sage advice above, I'd go with, "if you wish to **reactivate** your plan, **just** top up **your account** with 50 dollars."

Answer (score 1):

Activate would only be used for a brand-new plan. If the plan is frozen and needs the money get started again, then you would say reactivate. –
Canadian Yankee

However, "top up with 50 dollars" sounds strange in American English. Top up normally takes an object, like top up the gas tank, or top up your account.
We would probably just say add fifty dollars. There's a [discussion of the phrasing here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47302/to-top-up-a-mobile-phone)

Comment: comments to cw.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds natural to me. You could also say "start your cell phone plan".